How to change the email id of the user of Ubuntu without creating new user?
I installed ubuntu last year and used an online email account id which i dont use anymore to create a profile and it shows up even in my file manager

I want to change this email id but do not want to create a new user as I have done a lot of customisation and do not want to do it all over again.
Can anyone help me out with this?

That looks like an "online account". Go to Settings / Online accounts and change, add or delete accounts.

It is not clear where and how you used the email ID in Ubuntu. Ubuntu does not require an email ID during installation. Edit your question and clarify if the email ID is to access an online account or if you used it as your local username.

Thanks @Jos. It worked out :)
